# Angular 11 proxy not proxing

Tags: angular, proxy, angular11

I have this current configuration in the proxy.conf file

```
{
  "/mgr/admin/api/*": {
    "target": "http://actual-target.com/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

I need to have the `mgr` part parametric as well since it can be `mgr-hash` or stay just `mgr`.

I tried to add a regex in order to fit the possible mgr values like following, but without any luck

```
{
  "/mgr[A-Za-z0-9-]*/admin/api/*": {
    "target": "http://actual-target.com/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

In the first case it is proxing but in the second one it isn't. Any hint?
I am calling `/mgr/admin/api/login` url. why in the second configuration it is not proxing? Thanks in advance